# How do I modify my matplotlib FuncAnimation init_func to remove artifacts that were introduced by using twinx?

Tags: animation, matplotlib

Summary: I created a script for drawing strip charts with the matplotlib animation framework to support multiple y-axes using the Axes.twinx(), which resulted in an artifact on the plot which I can't remove. I think I need to modify the animation init_func to account for the multiple axes.

Python 2.7, matplotlib 2.0.2 with the Qt backend, and conda 4.3.18, running on Ubuntu Linux 17.04.

Full Description: I created strip chart drawing program based on the matplotlib strip chart demo:

https://matplotlib.org/examples/animation/strip_chart_demo.html

I modified it to help some EE's on a project including rewriting it in a more procedural style so they were more comfortable working with it (not sure how successful that was, we're still talking about it), adding support for multiple lines, and changed it so it was continuously scrolling left.

The script includes a makeChart() function that creates a series of Line2D's in a loop, and adds them to a list, and returns them to the caller:

```
lines = [] 
for iline in range(0,linesPerPlot):
    lines.append(makeLine(ax, maxt, dt, ymin, ymax, colors[iline % len(colors)]))

return lines
```

When I added multiple lines there was an artifact that appeared when running with blit=True that I got rid of by adding an init_function.

The init function is simple and looks like this:

```
def initDisplay(lines):
    """Init display."""
    return lines
```

When the script executes makeChart() is called and returns a list of Line2D's that are being plotted, it creates a lambda that wraps the init function that is then passed to FuncAnimation:

```
lines = makeChart(ax, secondsPerPlot, secondsPerSample, linesPerPlot, ymin, ymax)
...
init = lambda: initDisplay(lines)
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update, emitter, init_func=init, interval=millisPerFrame, blit=True)
```

The result works reasonable well:

[image: strip chart with multiple lines]

And an example with that displays some generated sin waves is here:

https://gist.github.com/mdkrajnak/f7cfd3f720453d53da4a80fa45df3b66

Later I made an additional modification so that each line had an independent y-axis by using Axes.twinx. After the modification there's now an artifact that I cannot remove that appears to be left over from the first time the first line is rendered.

[image: plot with artifact]

The new inner loop in makeChart() looks like:

```
lines = [] 
lines.append(makeLine(ax, maxt, dt, ymin, ymax, colors[0]))    
for iline in range(1,linesPerPlot):
    twin_ax = ax.twinx()
    lines.append(makeLine(twin_ax, maxt, dt, ymin, ymax, colors[iline % len(colors)]))

return lines
```

And the full code is here:

https://gist.github.com/mdkrajnak/e8b37300545f3ffea651d628933bd0ee

I tried modifying the init function so that it returned a list with both the lines and axes:

```
def initDisplay(lines, axs):
    """Init display."""
    return lines + axs
```

And the makeChart() function so it returned the axes along with the lines in the sequence of artists that it returned:

```
lines = []
axs = []

# Add first line, then add subsequent lines sharing the x-axis.  
lines.append(makeLine(ax, maxt, dt, ymin, ymax, colors[0]))   
axs.append(ax) 
for iline in range(1,linesPerPlot):
    twin_ax = ax.twinx()
    lines.append(makeLine(twin_ax, maxt, dt, ymin, ymax, colors[iline % len(colors)]))
    axs.append(twin_ax)

return lines, axs
```

The full code is here:

https://gist.github.com/mdkrajnak/e6eaca509cd8321b9b56a4d25c3e1e80

But this version fails with "AttributeError: draw_artist can only be used after an initial draw which caches the render"

```
File "/home/mdk/opt/miniconda3/envs/p2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/animation.py", line 1123, in _post_draw self._blit_draw(self._drawn_artists, self._blit_cache)
File "/home/mdk/opt/miniconda3/envs/p2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/animation.py", line 1138, in _blit_draw a.axes.draw_artist(a)
File "/home/mdk/opt/miniconda3/envs/p2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py", line 2441, in draw_artist raise AttributeError(msg)
AttributeError: draw_artist can only be used after an initial draw which caches the render
```

My thinking is still that the init function needs to return the axes along with the lines, but I need to somehow cause an initial draw of the axes before the init function is called. Is there something I can to to prerender the axes, or is there something else I need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that blitting is performed per axes. So it might be that the procedure is

```
for ax in all axes:
    get axes background
    draw line
```

This means that the first line is part of the background from the second axes and as such will be part of every successive frame.

The only solution I can think of at the moment is to make the lines invisible until the backgrounds of all axes have been stored for blitting.

```
line = Line2D(tdata, ydata, color=color, visible=False)
```

Only after the first call to `updateLines` turn them visible again.

```
n = [0]
def updateLines(lines, arrays):
    """Update individual lines and return a sequence of artists to the animator."""
    artists = []
    for iline in range(len(lines)):
        artists.append(updateLine(lines[iline], arrays[iline]))
        if n[0] > 0:
            lines[iline].set_visible(True)
    n[0] += 1
    return artists
```

[image]

Complete code:

```css
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D

import math

# Initalize script constants
ymin = -1.1
ymax = 1.1

linesPerPlot = 3

samplesPerFrame = 1
framesPerSecond = 20
secondsPerPlot = 5

# Calculate dependent constants
samplesPerSecond = samplesPerFrame * framesPerSecond
samplesPerPlot =  samplesPerSecond * secondsPerPlot
secondsPerSample = 1.0/samplesPerSecond
millisPerFrame = 1000.0/framesPerSecond

# Define core functions

def makeLine(ax, maxt, dt, ymin, ymax, color):
"""Make an empty Line2D for the initial chart."""
nvalues = int(round(maxt/dt))

tdata = [dt*tm for tm in range(nvalues)]
ydata = [0 for tm in range(nvalues)]

line = Line2D(tdata, ydata, color=color, visible=False) ### <- visible false
ax.add_line(line)
ax.set_ylim(ymin, ymax)

return line

    
def makeChart(ax, maxt, dt, linesPerPlot, ymin, ymax):
"""Make a chart and return a list of the lines it contains."""
colors = [ 'r', 'b', 'g', 'k' ]
lines = []

# Add first line, then add subsequent lines sharing the x-axis.  
lines.append(makeLine(ax, maxt, dt, ymin, ymax, colors[0]))    
for iline in range(1,linesPerPlot):
    twin_ax = ax.twinx()
    lines.append(makeLine(twin_ax, maxt, dt, ymin, ymax, colors[iline % len(colors)]))

ax.set_xlim(0, maxt)

return lines


def initDisplay(lines):
"""Init display."""
return lines


def updateLine(line, ys):
"""Update the data in one line, popping off the last value."""
tdata, ydata = line.get_data()
for y in ys:
    ydata.append(y)
    ydata.pop(0)
line.set_data(tdata, ydata)

return line

n = [0]
def updateLines(lines, arrays):
"""Update individual lines and return a sequence of artists to the animator."""
artists = []
for iline in range(len(lines)):
    artists.append(updateLine(lines[iline], arrays[iline]))
    if n[0] > 0:
        lines[iline].set_visible(True)
n[0] += 1
return artists


def emitData(linesPerPlot, samplesPerFrame):
"""Create the data that will be plotted."""
nsample = 0
while True:
    samples = [[] for i in range(linesPerPlot)]
    for isample in range(samplesPerFrame):
        nsample = nsample + 1
        for iline in range(linesPerPlot):
            pi_increment = (math.pi/(10.0 * (iline+1)))
            samples[iline].append(math.sin(nsample * pi_increment))

    yield samples


# Make chart.
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
lines = makeChart(ax, secondsPerPlot, secondsPerSample, linesPerPlot, ymin, ymax)

# Start the animator.
update = lambda samples: updateLines(lines, samples)
emitter = lambda: emitData(linesPerPlot, samplesPerFrame)
init = lambda: initDisplay(lines)

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update, emitter, init_func=init, interval=millisPerFrame, blit=True)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Works for me, thanks! This was not very intuitive to me, is there a an recommendation to make to the maplotlib project or is just  something that will become more apparent after working with matplotlib longer?

Comment: No it's not intuitive and it might not be the best possible way. But it's the only one I can think of. It also took me 2 hours to come up with the idea of leaving out the first frame by making it invisible. I think that actually nobody has ever thought about such an issue when designing the   FuncAnimation.